# Can't specify destination of extension module, can't add python modules

Tags: python, c++, pip, cython, setup.py

I work on NetworKit (https://networkit.iti.kit.edu/), a hybrid C++/Cython/Python project. I want to prepare the `setup.py` script so that NetworKit can easily be installed via `pip install networkit`. However, there are some difficulties.

First, let me describe the directory structure of the repository and what setup.py currently does.

Directory structure:

```
NetworKit/
|- setup.py
|- README.rst
|- MANIFEST.in
|-src/
  |-cpp/
    | c++ header and source files in subfolders
  |-python/
    |- __init__.py
    |- _NetworKit.pyx
    | various python modules
```

`python setup.py develop` currently does 3 things:

- invoke SCons to build the C++ core
- build the extension module in the folder `src/python` (which needs the C++ core)
- place a link in pythonX/dist-packages/ which links to `src/python`.

Here's the relevant excerpt from setup.py:

```
if ("install" in sys.argv) :
    build_NetworKit()
src = ["_NetworKit.pyx"]    
modules = [Extension("_NetworKit",
                src,
                language = "c++",
                extra_compile_args=["-fopenmp", "-std=c++11", "-O3", "-DNOGTEST"],
                extra_link_args=["-fopenmp", "-std=c++11"],
                libraries=["NetworKit-Core-{0}".format(optimize)],
                library_dirs=["../../"])]

for e in modules:
    e.cython_directives = {"embedsignature" : True}

setup(name="networkit",
    version="3.2",
    url="https://networkit.iti.kit.edu/",
    keywords = "graph algorithm network analysis social network",
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
    ext_modules=modules)
```

What did I achieve so far:
With `MANIFEST.in` I successfully included all C++ header and source files in the package. `python setup.py sdist` and `pip install networkit` from PyPI's test server successfully compiles the library, creates the extension and places it under `pythonX/dist-packages/`. This is where the problems start:

1. I want the extension to be placed under `pythonX/dist-packages/networkit-x.y/`. Also, _NetworKit.pyx is not included automatically although it's the source for the Extension module; I  had to include it via `MANIFEST.in`.
2. I tried to add the python module and submodules by adding `packages` and `package_dir` to `setup(...)` in the above excerpt. While `sdist` worked and included all `.py` files, I usually ended up with `directory ... not existing` during the installation. In addition, I tried adapting the repository structure as well as the location of `setup.py` to be more in line with the official recommendations. However, that also didn't help.

Also to summarize what exactly should be installed where: The Python modules and submodules as well as the Extension are supposed to go under `pythonX/dist-packages/networkit-x.y/`.

Besides the probably not very proper directory structure, what am I missing in the `setup(...)` configuration to get the extension as well as the Python modules properly installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'd want the distutils setup() keyword `package_dir={'':'src/python'}` to indicate the root folder of your python modules, and secondly you can use the setuptools function `find_packages(root_dir, include=[], exclude=[])` to find your necessary packages/modules. So you'd likely want to use `packages=find_packages('src/python')`.

See [here](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) in the setuptools documentation for more information.

Setuptools will always install your package under `../site-packages/<packagename>`. `dist-packages` is a debian addition for their system package manager's installed packages; but your python should look under the correct `site-packages` folder as well.

If you wish to easily install and uninstall packages while developing, I would use `pip install -e .` and `pip uninstall -y networkit` respectively. Having pip manage the installation allows it to be uninstalled as well (so you can check everything went alright, etc).

Comment: As you said, `dist-packages` is debian only but as it seems there is no `site-packages` on my system. However, thanks for the hint as that will be useful when I try it on other systems.